# trying to get MySQL data into nested json file for d3?

Tags: mysql, json, treeview, d3.js, subquery

I am trying to get MySQL database data into json format. My file needs to be in the format of nested parents and children. (see snippet) This is because I am trying to use a d3 data visualization (collapsible tree layout) that requires that the json data be formatted in a certain way. Below I have attached a snippet of what I the json file to look like. I am having some issues trying to write nested sql statements to do this. I have also attached a visual of my database to see what I am dealing with. Any advice will help greatly. Thanks! [image]

The json format I am trying to get is something like this:

```
{
  "name": "Projects",
  "children": [
   {
     "name":"category_name#1", "description":"category",
     "children": [
    {
            "name":"sub_category_name1",
            "description":"category description text here",
                    "children":[
                    {"name": "project1",
                     "description":"project 1 text goes here",
                                "children":[
                        {"name":"mike", "email":"xxx@mail.com"},
                        {"name":"dan", "email":"xxx@gmail.com"}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                    "name": "project2",
                    "description":"project 2 text goes here",
                                "children":[
                        {"name":"steve", "email":"xxx@mail.com"},
                        {"name":"chris", "email":"xxx@gmail.com"}
                                ]                       
                    }
                    ]   
            },
            {
            "name": "sub_category_name2",
            "description":"sub category description text goes here..",
            "children": [
                {"name": "project3",
                "description":"project3 text goes here ",
                "children":[
                    {"name":"Alex", "email":"xxx@gmail.com"}                        
                ]                   
                }
            ]
            }

    ]
    },
    .
    . //more categories with children of subcategories and sub_cat children of projects
    .
}
```

Comment: Generated dynamically on a page request using a language (which one? ruby? python? php?), or just dumping the current state out to a static file to be read by d3?

Comment: sorry for not mentioning it earlier. I am using php and yes dynamically on a page request.

Comment: Did you find the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've had success with this tutorial in the past:
http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/using-mysql-database-as-source-of-data.html

In short what you'll do is create a php file that connects to MySql, performs a query and translates the results into json. You'll then use this file in place of the data source in your d3 code.

Comment: ok thanks. I will give it a try. The only problem is I will need to be sure to add "name:" and "children:" tags where necessary because the particular d3 visual I am trying to create needs the data in that format.

Comment: @user1899872 Did you get your solution ?

Comment: How an you get it to do it like the flare.json example?  I don't think this answers the question.