# MySQL to nested JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, database, multidimensional-array

[This is almost exactly what I want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16181917/trying-to-get-mysql-data-into-nested-json-file-for-d3), but that question hasn't been answered and it's been a year. I've managed to get close, I think, but numbers are being printed as keys. In my example it shows up on line 47, but it is repeated for every "course_name" in the actual file.

```
[
 {
  "school_name": "Projects",
  "terms": [
    {
      "term_name":"category_name#1",
      "departments": [
        {
          "department_name":"sub_category_name1",
          "department_code":"category code text here",
          "courses":[
            {
              "course_name": "project1",
              "course_code":"project 1 code text goes here",
              "sections":[
                {
                  "section_code":"mike", 
                  "unique_id":"xxx@mail.com"
                },
                {
                  "section_code":"dan", 
                  "unique_id":"xxx@gmail.com"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "course_name": "project2",
              "course_code":"project 2 code text goes here",
              "sections":[
                {
                  "section_code":"steve", 
                  "unique_id":"xxx@mail.com"
                },
                {
                  "section_code":"chris", 
                  "unique_id":"xxx@gmail.com"
                }
              ]                       
            }
          ]   
        },
        {
          "department_name": "sub_category_name2",
          "department_code":"sub category description text goes here..",
          "courses": {
-->>>       "69": {
                "course_name": "project3",
                "course_code":"project3 code text goes here ",
                "sections":[
                  {
                    "section_code":"Alex", 
                    "unique_id":"xxx@gmail.com"
                  }                        
                ]                   
              }
             }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Here is the query I am using and an example of data being returned.

```
SELECT school_name, term_name, department_name, department_code, course_code, course_name, section_code, magento_course_id
        FROM schools INNER JOIN term_names ON schools.id=term_names.school_id INNER JOIN departments ON schools.id=departments.school_id INNER JOIN
        adoptions ON departments.id=adoptions.department_id

"UCA-2" "SPRING 2013" "ACCOUNTING" "ACCT" "3315" "COST ACCOUNTING" "10258" 10311
```

What I have is being generated with this code.

```
$row_array = array();
$terms = array();
$departments = array();
$courses = array();

$h = 0;
$i = 0;
$j = 0;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetch)) {
  $row_array[$row['school_name']]['school_name'] = $row['school_name'];

  $akey = array_search($row['term_name'], $terms);
  if ($akey === FALSE) {
    $m = $h++;
    $terms[] = $row['term_name'];
    $row_array[$row['school_name']]['terms'][$m]['term_name'] = $row['term_name'];
  } else {
    $m = $akey;
  }

  $key = array_search($row['department_code'], $departments);
  if ($key === FALSE) {
    $k = $i++;
    $departments[] = $row['department_code'];
    $row_array[$row['school_name']]['terms'][$m]['departments'][$k]['department_name'] = $row['department_name'];
    $row_array[$row['school_name']]['terms'][$m]['departments'][$k]['department_code'] = $row['department_code'];
  } else {
    $k = $key;
  }

  $skey = array_search($row['course_code'], $courses);
  if ($skey === FALSE) {
    $l = $j++;
    $courses[] = $row['course_code'];
    $row_array[$row['school_name']]['terms'][$m]['departments'][$k]['courses'][$l]['course_name'] = $row['course_name'];
    $row_array[$row['school_name']]['terms'][$m]['departments'][$k]['courses'][$l]['course_code'] = $row['course_code'];
  } else {
    $l = $skey;
  }

  $row_array[$row['school_name']]['terms'][$m]['departments'][$k]['courses'][$l]['sections'][] = array('section_code' => $row['section_code'], 'unique_id' => $row['magento_course_id']);
}
```

How do I generate this JSON without those numbers showing up?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? You want the courses to be an array of objects instead of a big key/value object? [{course},{course2}] instead of {key:{course},key2:{course2}}?

Comment: I have an idea you are making this FAR TO COMPLICATED, post the query and some example data returned from the query.

Comment: @snowman4415 what I'm trying to output is the pattern up until line 46 of my example. That is where the pattern changes.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've added my query to my question and example data. This has been the simplest method I've tried to use because of the specific format I need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some key & encoding problems. Too much key usage, excessive loops in your code. Maybe you should tidy your sql query.

Since you are setting keys for courses, JSON shows it.

Try removing the key after "['courses']" in your last line such as;

```
Change  ['courses'][$l] to  ['courses'][]
```

At the end, encode the array for JSON.

```
 $result = json_encode($result);
```